# How to replace text using regex with condition?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace a link as plain text format to html format.

But I got the issue that, I don't know how to prepend the `http://` prefix for the new replacement if in the original link does not exist.

```
var text        = "google.com and http://google.com";
var pattern     = /(\b((https?)\:\/\/)?[A-Za-z0-9]+\.(com|net|org))/ig;
text            = text.replace(pattern,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>");
```

I meant:

1. If: `google.com` will be replaced `<a href="http://google.com">google.com</a>`
2. If: `http://google.com` will be replaced `<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>`

Comment: Just so you know.. `www.google.com` is not handled by your regex

Comment: I just want to make my question is as simple as. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [overload of `String.replace` that takes a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
var text = "google.com and http://google.com";
var pattern = /(\b((https?)\:\/\/)?[A-Za-z0-9]+\.(com|net|org))/ig;

text = text.replace(pattern, function (str, p1)
{
    var addScheme = p1.indexOf('http://') === -1
                    && p1.indexOf('https://') === -1;

    return '<a href="' + (addScheme ? 'http://' : '') + p1 + '">' + p1 + '</a>';
});

// text is:
// '<a href="http://google.com">google.com</a> and <a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>'
```

Comment: And @parapura rajkumar is correct; the regex will not handle `www.google.com` (really, any subdomains), so you might want to fix that.